# Does an OutputStreamWriter without buffering exist?

Tags: java, buffer, outputstream, writer

I need to convert a stream of `char` into a stream of `byte`s, i.e. I need an adapter from a `java.io.Writer` interface to a `java.io.OutputStream`, supporting any valid `Charset` which I will have as a configuration parameter.

However, the `java.io.OutputStreamWriter` class has a hidden secret: the `sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder` object it delegates to underneath creates an 8192 byte (8KB) buffer, even if you don't ask it to.

The problem is, at the `OutputStream` end I have inserted a wrapper that needs to *count the amount of bytes being written*, so that it immediately stops execution of the source system once a specific amount of bytes has been output. And if `OutputStreamWriter` is creating an 8K buffer, I simply get notified of the amount of bytes generated **too late** because they will only reach my counter when the buffer is *flushing* (so there will be already more than 8,000 already-generated bytes waiting for me at the `OutputStreamWriter` buffer).

So the question is, **is there anywhere in the Java runtime a `Writer` -> `OutputStream` bridge that can run unbuffered**?

I would really, really hate to have to write this myself :(...

**NOTE**: hitting *flush()* on the `OutputStreamWriter` for each write is not a valid alternative. That brings a large performance penalty (there's a `synchronized` block involved at the `StreamEncoder`).

**NOTE 2**: I understand it might be necessary to keep a small char overflow at the bridge in order to compute surrogates. It's not that I need to stop the execution of the source system in the very moment it generates the n-th byte (that would not be possible given bytes can come to me in the form of a larger `byte[]` in a `write` call). But I need to stop it *asap*, and waiting for an 8K, 2K or even 200-byte buffer to flush would simply be too late.

Comment: Arguably it *can't* be fully unbuffered - if you call `write` with just the first half of a surrogate pair, for most encodings the writer would *have* to store that and wait for the second character before writing anything.

Comment: Well yes, of course, I understand that. But there's a difference between a couple of buffered chars needed to compute a surrogate pair and an 8K buffer...

Comment: I don't think there's any "of course" there - I suspect many readers will assume you mean no buffering at all, and that you might not be aware of surrogate pairs. I suggest you edit the question to clarify that. (Would it be "too late" if the first call to `write` didn't stop execution, for example?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As you have already detected the `StreamEncoder` used by `OutputStreamWriter` has a buffer size of 8KB and there is no interface to change that size.

But the following snippet gives you a way to obtain a `Writer` for a `OutputStream` which internally also uses a `StreamEncoder` but now has a user-defined buffer size:

```
String charSetName = ...
CharsetEncoder encoder = Charset.forName(charSetName).newEncoder();

OutputStream out = ...
int bufferSize = ...

WritableByteChannel channel = Channels.newChannel(out);
Writer writer = Channels.newWriter(channel, encoder, bufferSize);
```

Comment: I cannot give you enough points for this. It works like a charm, thanks so much.
The only thing I worry a bit about is that the spec defines that `bufferSize` as the *minimum* buffer size. But I see the standard implementation at `sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder` simply uses this as a fixed size, so that should do. Thanks again.